# Windows Tool for Extracting enhanced images from video

Tags: capturing, photos

I am looking for a Windows tool for extracting photos from videos, taking advantage of similarity between subsequent frames to enhance the captured still images.

There used to be a product for this, Topaz Moment, but this is no longer offered.

I’m interested in this, as I want to extract photos from my vacation video.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If your actually looking to produce a single image from a number of temporally-local frames,  then your probably looking at doing some kind of superresolution or drizzle integration. There are tools that do this. I use them for astrophotography myself, such as Registax and AutoStakkert!! 2. These are designed to generate astronomy images, such as planets, the moon, the sun, from video sequences.

For these applications to work, they expect that the entire video sequence is generally going to be of an identical subject, and that only the quality of the contents differs. This implies that one has the ability to track or otherwise maintain identical subject framing. AS!2 is the one I use most, and it will sort the video frames by quality such that ones overpowered by seeing are dropped, and the best are kept and stacked.

The results can be quite stunning, detail can far surpass that of a single frame or even a high quality still.

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, however it's the closest thing I can think of. Maybe the terms *super resolution* and *drizzle* might help in your search.

Comment: 10x. I was looking more for a low cost Windows tool to extract photos from my trip to italy video  :$